# Cross check if multiple variable are equal in php

Tags: php

Is there any efficient way to check these multiple variable values with each other?
Example: If value of `$v1` is **abc** and value of `$v2` is **abc** and other variables are empty then return error because two values are same.
Another Example: If value of `$v1` is **abc** and value of `$v4` is **abc** and other variables are empty then return error because two values are same.
Like check every variable with every other variable, if it's same with anyone then return an error.

```
$v1 = $_POST['v1'];
$v2 = $_POST['v2'];
$v3 = $_POST['v3'];
$v4 = $_POST['v4'];
$v5 = $_POST['v5'];
$v6 = $_POST['v6'];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$v1 = 1;
$v2 = 2;
$v3 = 3;
$v4 = 4;
$v5 = 5;
$v6 = 5;
$values = [$v1, $v2, $v3, $v4, $v5, $v6];
if (count($values) !== count(array_unique($values))) {
    echo 'Duplicates found';
}
```

**[DEMO](http://phpio.net/s/169t)**

### UPDATED

You can easily use [**array_count_values**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) function to determine which values are duplicated.
I put it here: http://phpio.net/s/16bh

Comment: @SukhchainSingh: If you name inputs `name="v[]"` then you will already have a `$_POST['v']` array.

Comment: This will not work if two `$_POST` entries or more are empty. [Check here](https://eval.in/683047)

Comment: This sample is about to find duplicated values. I dot not care about the input. So you can still optimize code.

Comment: I'm just interpreting what the OP wrote : If value of $v1 is abc and value of $v2 is abc and other variables are empty then return error **because two values are same**.

Answer (score 1):

Put them as keys to the assoc array and then check its len.

```
$vars = [];
$keys = ['v1', ..., 'v6'];
foreach ($keys as $k) {
    $vars[$_POST[$k]] = true;
} 

if (count($vars) != count($keys)) {
    echo 'Duplicates found!';
}
```

Explanation:

```
$_POST = [
    'v1' => 'abc',
    'v2' => 'cde',
    'v3' => 'abc',
]
$vars = [];
$keys = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3'];

// 1st foreach iteration:
$vars['abc'] = true;  // $vars = ['abc' => true];

// 2nd foreach iteration:
$vars['cde'] = true;  // $vars = ['abc' => true, 'cde' => true];

// 3rd foreach iteration:
$vars['abc'] = true;  // Again 'abc'! $vars is still ['abc' => true, 'cde' => true];

print_r(count($vars) == count($keys));  // 2 == 3
```

This algorithm has `O(n)` complexity while using `array_unique()` could be `O(n*log(n))` if the last one uses sorting under the hood.

Comment: @SukhchainSingh, please look at the example code I've added.

Comment: i have checked but the length of all variables will be around 4-5 characters.

Comment: WTF is [array_length](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=array_length&lang=en&scope=404quickref) ?

Answer (score 0):

I´ve added comments, if you do not understand something feel free to ask, hope it will help you understand this :)

```
<?php
    $f1 = 'abc';
    $f2 = 'ac';
    $f3 = 'abc';

    $t1 = 'b';
    $t2 = 'a';
    $t3 = 'abc';

    // push to array
    $array_f[] = $f1;
    $array_f[] = $f2;
    $array_f[] = $f3;

    $array_t[] = $t1;
    $array_t[] = $t2;
    $array_t[] = $t3;

    // count($array_f) returns number of elements in array and array_unique removes duplicates from array
    // so if the length of original array is same as array without duplicates, then there weren´t duplicates else there were
    if(count($array_f) === count(array_unique($array_f))) echo 'array_t is unique return true</br>';
    else echo 'array_t is not unique return false</br>';

    if(count($array_t) === count(array_unique($array_t))) echo 'array_f is unique return true</br>';
    else echo 'array_ fis not unique return false</br>';

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go here is to use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) :

```
<?php
$array = array($_POST['v1'], $_POST['v2'], $_POST['v3'], $_POST['v4'], $_POST['v5'], $_POST['v6']);
$array_unique = array_unique($array);

if ($array_unique == $array) {
    // No duplicates
} else {
    // duplicates
}
?>
```

EDIT : If you only want the `$_POST` values that are not empty :

```
<?php
$array = array();
if ($_POST['v1'] != '')
    $array[] = $_POST['v1'];
if ($_POST['v2'] != '')
    $array[] = $_POST['v2'];
if ($_POST['v3'] != '')
    $array[] = $_POST['v3'];
if ($_POST['v4'] != '')
    $array[] = $_POST['v4'];
if ($_POST['v5'] != '')
    $array[] = $_POST['v5'];
if ($_POST['v6'] != '')
    $array[] = $_POST['v6'];

if (count($array) < 2) {
    // Zero or one element in the array
} else {
    $array_unique = array_unique($array);

    if ($array_unique == $array) {
        // No duplicates
    } else {
        // duplicates
    }
}
?>
```

(Of course, the array building could be enhanced with a `for` loop)

Check it here : https://eval.in/683045

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the case in which only one value of `$_POST` is set.

Comment: it always returns a duplicate value.

Comment: It (the second code) works well, check the [fiddle](https://eval.in/683045)

Answer (score 0):

```
$filtered = array_reduce(array_keys($_POST), function($carry, $key){
    // get all v[0..9]* variables from post
    if (preg_match('^/v\d+$/i',$key)) {
        $carry[$key]=$_POST[$key];
    }
    return $carry;
}, array());

$checked = array_unique($filtered);

$hasDuplicates = count($filtered) != count($checked);
```

another version (if you need to check exact POST-keys)

```
$keys = array('v1','v2','v3');
$filtered = array_intersect_keys($_POST, array_flip($keys));
$checked = array_unique($filtered);
$hasDuplicates = count($filtered) != count($checked);
```